# Javascript gerando caracteres que não estão presentes

Tags: javascript, html, xml, formulário

O código abaixo está em `XML` e é um formulário que está sendo usado para conveniência gerando código `HTML`, tudo que for digitado no `input` será enviado para `textarea` já com o `HTML` através de javascript.
O `checkbox` está com script para **travar** o botão de confirmação, e também gera `HTML` porém em vez de simplesmente `</div>\n</div>` o resultado sai como `on</div>\n</div>`, mas não tem `on` na string, o que é isso?

O formulário está hospedado no **blogger** [neste link](https://stacklinks.blogspot.com/).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html b:version='2' class='v2' expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data' xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'> 
  <head>
    <meta content='IE=EmulateIE7' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'/> 
    <b:if cond='data:blog.isMobile'> 
      <meta content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0' name='viewport'/> 
    <b:else/> 
      <meta content='width=1100' name='viewport'/> 
    </b:if> 
    <b:include data='blog' name='all-head-content'/> 
    <title><data:blog.pageTitle/></title>
   <b:skin><![CDATA[/*

]]></b:skin>

<style type='text/css'>
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #5190e2;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #5190e2;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #3d679e;
}

a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #5190e2;
}
</style>


<style type='text/css'>
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=text], select, textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    resize: vertical;
}

label {
    padding: 12px 12px 12px 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}

.container {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
}

.conf {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 280px;
}

.col-25 {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    margin-top: 6px;
}

.col-75 {
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
    margin-top: 6px;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: &quot;&quot;;
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 600px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .col-25, .col-75, input[type=submit] {
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
}
</style>   
  </head>
  <body>

<div style='margin-top:50px; '><center><h1>LINKS</h1></center></div>  

<div class='container' style='margin-top:50px;'>
<form autocomplete='off' onsubmit='return submitted()'> 
  <div class='row'><div class='col-25'><label for='01'>SERVIDOR: </label></div><div class='col-75'><input id='01' name='link' required='required' type='text'/></div></div>
  <div class='row'><div class='col-25'><label for='02'>LINK: </label></div><div class='col-75'><input id='02' name='link' type='text'/></div></div>
  <div class='conf'>CONFIRMAR:<input id='myCheck' name='link' onclick='bloqueio()' type='checkbox'/></div>
  <div class='row'><input disabled='disabled' id='confirmar' type='submit' value='CONCLUIR'/></div> 
  <div class='row'><textarea name='link' style='height:200px'/></div> 
</form>
</div>

<div style='margin-top:50px; '> 
<center>
  <p class='author'>&#169; Gerador de postagens do <a href='https://www.nextdark.com/'> Next Dark</a> <b>By: Mark Vaaz</b></p></center></div>


  <b:section class='navbar' id='navbar' maxwidgets='1' showaddelement='no'/>


<script>
function bloqueio() {
    document.getElementById(&quot;confirmar&quot;).disabled = false;
}
</script>


<script>
function submitted() {


   if((document.getElementsByName(&quot;link&quot;)[0].value)!=&quot;&quot;){
     link0= &#39;&lt;div class=&quot;dropdown&quot;&gt;\n  &lt;button class=&quot;dropbtn&quot;&gt;&#39;+ document.getElementsByName(&quot;link&quot;)[0].value +&#39;&lt;/button&gt;\n  &lt;div class=&quot;dropdown-content&quot;&gt;\n&#39;;
   }else{
     link0=&quot;&quot;;
   }

   if((document.getElementsByName(&quot;link&quot;)[1].value)!=&quot;&quot;){
     link1= &#39;    &lt;a href=&quot;&#39;+ document.getElementsByName(&quot;link&quot;)[1].value +&#39;&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot;&gt;LINK - 01&lt;/a&gt;\n&#39;;
   }else{
     link1=&quot;&quot;;
   }

   if((document.getElementsByName(&quot;link&quot;)[2].value)!=&quot;&quot;){
     link2= document.getElementsByName(&quot;link&quot;)[2].value +&#39;&lt;/div&gt;\n&lt;/div&gt;&#39;;
   }else{
     link2=&quot;&quot;;
   }

   var formValue = link0 + link1 + link2;
   document.getElementsByName(&quot;link&quot;)[3].value = formValue;
   return false;
}
</script>
  </body> 
</html>
```

**Scripts decodificados:**

```
<script>
function bloqueio() {
    document.getElementById("confirmar").disabled = false;
}
</script>


<script>
function submitted() {


   if((document.getElementsByName("link")[0].value)!=""){
     link0= '<div class="dropdown">\n  <button class="dropbtn">'+ document.getElementsByName("link")[0].value +'</button>\n  <div class="dropdown-content">\n';
   }else{
     link0="";
   }

   if((document.getElementsByName("link")[1].value)!=""){
     link1= '    <a href="'+ document.getElementsByName("link")[1].value +'" target="_blank">LINK - 01</a>\n';
   }else{
     link1="";
   }

   if((document.getElementsByName("link")[2].value)!=""){
     link2= document.getElementsByName("link")[2].value +'</div>\n</div>';
   }else{
     link2="";
   }

   var formValue = link0 + link1 + link2;
   document.getElementsByName("link")[3].value = formValue;
   return false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este valor está vindo do seu checkbox neste momento

```
link2= document.getElementsByName("link")[2].value +'</div>\n</div>';
```

o **value** do **checkbox** é on...

Comment: É pra vir mesmo esse valor do checkbox, mas como faço pra não vir o "on"?

Comment: tirando o document.getElementsByName("link")[2].value